# Imported component and console message

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I have a problem with props in imported component.
I imported component with dialog template and I want display text from props and it works, but I have errors in console.

In console I see this error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'test' of null"

But after open dialog value is correctly.

How can I fix this problem so that the error in console doesn't show up?

My code:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-card class="">
          <TipItem v-for="tip in tips" :key="tip.id" v-on:open-dialog="openTipDetailsDialog(tip)"></TipItem>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <TipDetailsDialog :dialog="tipDetailsDialog" :tip="tipDetails" v-on:close-dialog="tipDetailsDialog = false"></TipDetailsDialog>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  import TipItem from "../components/TipItem";
  import TipDetailsDialog from "../components/TipDetailsDialog";

  export default {
    name: "Tips",
    components: {
      TipItem,
      TipDetailsDialog
    },
    data: () => ({
      tips: [],
      tipDetailsDialog: false,
      tipDetails: null
    }),
    methods: {
      openTipDetailsDialog(tip) {
        this.tipDetailsDialog = true;
        this.tipDetails = tip;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

TipDetailsDialog

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
      :value="dialog"
      fullscreen
      hide-overlay
      transition="dialog-bottom-transition"
      @input="$emit('close-dialog')"
  >
    <v-card class="rounded-0">
      <v-toolbar color="primary">
        <v-toolbar-title>Szczegóły</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn icon dark @click="$emit('close-dialog')">
          <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="6">
            <v-card>
              {{ tip.test }}
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="6">
            <v-card>
              {{ tip.test2 }}
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "TipDetailsDialog",
    props: ["dialog", "tip"]
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tipDetails` is initialized as `null`, and then bound to `<TipDetailsDialog>.tip`, which causes it to try to render `tip.test` (where `tip` is `null`).

Since `TipDetailsDialog` doesn't really render anything meaningful without a populated `tip`, that component should probably be conditionally rendered only when `tipDetails` is truthy:

```html
<TipDetailsDialog v-if="tipDetails" :tip="tipDetails" />
```

Answer (score -1):

> `tipDetails` is initialized as `null`, and then bound to
> `<TipDetailsDialog>.tip`, which causes it to try to render `tip.test`
> (where `tip` is `null`).
>
> Since `TipDetailsDialog` doesn't really render anything meaningful
> without a populated `tip`, that component should probably be
> conditionally rendered only when `tipDetails` is truthy:
>
> `html <TipDetailsDialog v-if="tipDetails" :tip="tipDetails" />`

Or you can set a default value to the prop:

```
    props: {
        tip: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: () => ""
        },
    },
```